# How to enable flyspell in org-mode by default

Tags: emacs, org-mode, flyspell

In emacs, I want `flyspell-mode` to be enabled by default whenever I am in `org-mode`.

Based on different examples I've seen in emacs documentation I've tried adding various lines to my `.emacs` file one at a time, such as:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

and

```
(dolist (hook '(text-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))))
```

Neither of these will work. Please let me know the correct way to save myself from doing a `M-x flyspell-mode` every time I open an org-mode file.

Comment: `dolist` is for doing a bunch of stuff different than this.  You can do it like `mk1` suggested below, and if you have many things for the hook, you can do something like this:   `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1) ))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

Comment: I tried adding this line to my .emacs file, and it didn't work. I realized org-mode-hook was already defined toward the end of my file, so I added turn-on-flyspell there.... but still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the exact command that sets your `org-mode-hook`?

Comment: It was a long screwy mess under `customize-variable`, so I just wiped that out and added the line above and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a difference b/w this and "(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'(lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))"?